# Users passwords not working due to MachineKey IIS6 after migrating to IIS7 on a new server

Tags: asp.net, encryption, iis-7, machinekey

We had to migrate urgently from a Windows 2003 + IIS6 to a new Windows 2008 + IIS7

I have a couple of websites with the ASP.NET Membership Database with Hashed Passwords, on the new server users that were not being used work fine but users who recently used it cannot login (error is Invalid Password) Even after setting a new password same happens.

I can read the problem is with the MachineKey (it was not setup so it was using the comptuter MachineKey) I'm trying to set the IIS7 machinekey to the same as before so can get the users to work again.

We have over 500 users we dont know their passwords or anything so we cannot recreate them.

Any ideas on Where could I find the old MachineKey from the previous server (win 2003)?

Regards,

George

Answer (score 1):

Set this thing into your web.config for your application

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey  
    validationKey="<blah>"           
    decryptionKey="<blah>"
    validation="SHA1"
    decryption="AES"
    />
```

You need to use the old machine key to make it work.

Maybe you can try this to find out the machine key

http://aspnetresources.com/blog/how_to_read_auto_generated_machinekey

Comment: problem is it was not set on the application, so is there anything we can do?, I can also see 4 files here: C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys which I read may be it but cant get it to work yet, any ideas?

Comment: You can set it to application. Or you can set it to the site directly through the interface.

Comment: so you mean I set it to the application on the old server? and it will regenerate all the salts or something?, question is where do i get the old Machinekey from?, setting it up on the new one is not a problem. but I need the old value.

Comment: no. I mean there is a file called web.config in your site in your new server. Find out the old machine key (it should be in the web.config as well) and put it into your web.config.

Comment: yes, the only question is how do I get the old one. where is it?, it was not set on the web.config when the site was created, so it is not on the old web.config.

Comment: My best guest is in your application folder or site folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16569/discussion-between-george-and-maxisam)